# Migrating from VisualSVN on windows to linux based svn

Tags: svn, migration, repository, visualsvn

I'd like to migrate my svn repository from my local computer running windows and VisualSVN 2.1.2 to an svn app on [webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com/) (my Linux hosting solution).

Initially I tried dumping the svn:

> svnadmin dump *path_to_repository* > *dumpfile_name*

and loading it on the Linux machine

> svnadmin load *dumpfile_name*

I received the following error:

> svnadmin: Can't open file '*dumpfile_path_and_name*/format': Not a directory

I found that on my Windows machine I do have a format folder under the repository. So I copied the entire repository to the Linux machine and tried:

> svnadmin load *path_to_repository_copy*

I received the following error:

> svnadmin: Expected FS format between
>   '1' and '3'; found format '4'

what should I do?

Comment: Are both SVN server installations using the same version?

Comment: This question belongs on serverfault.com as it's not programming related but server-managing related.

Comment: oh, I wasn't aware that there was a serverfault.com
Where can I see the list of similar sites such as stackoverflow and serverfault?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for svnadmin load should be

`svnadmin load /path/to/repository < dumpfile`

See [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html)

Comment: Yup, that works.
I tried it before, but when I was inside the repository path. Once I exited it and tried it, it worked fine.

Comment: For the one that wants to do the opposite : [Converting Linux SVN Repos to Windows SVN Repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657010/converting-linux-svn-repos-to-windows-svn-repos)

Answer (score 1):

> svnadmin dump *path_to_repository* > *dumpfile_name*

This is correct.

> svnadmin load *dumpfile_name*
>
> svnadmin: Can't open file '*dumpfile_path_and_name*/format': Not a directory

**You must first**

```
svnadmin create path_to_repository
```

Then you can

```
svnadmin load path_to_repository < dumpfile_name
```

> I found that on my Windows machine I do have a format folder under the repository. So I copied  the entire repository to the Linux machine and tried:
>
> svnadmin load *path_to_repository_copy*
>
> svnadmin: Expected FS format between '1' and '3'; found format '4'

The whole point of the dump/load cycle rather than copying files straight is to work around database version differences.  In this case you have a newer svn on Windows than on your Linux box, so the Linux box complains it doesn't know about the new format (4).  (Your load syntax is also wrong, see 'svnadmin load --help', but it hits this error first.)