# Converting Linux SVN Repos to Windows SVN Repos

Tags: linux, svn, version-control, visualsvn

I have been tasked with finding out if our current Linux SVN Server can be migrated to MS Windows.

I have located and trialed a program called VisualSVN Server and it seems to do everything that we need, but I am clueless as to if it is possible to convert the current Linux repos to run on a Windows Server box.

I am new to the whole SVN application so please treat me gently with your answers :)

Thanks,

C.

Comment: @Matt: Any pointer on how to get 'Single Sign On' with a Linux/Apache SVN server and a bunch of Windows Workstations with users in a Windows domain?

Comment: @Didier: mod_ldap: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ldap.html

Comment: @Matt & @SirDarius: As far as I know (and use it!) `mod_ldap` on Linux/Apache allows authentication against a Windows Domain Controller. It works correctly, but it does not allow 'Single Sign On'. Do you have more precisions?

Comment: i don't really understand what you mean, you should open your own question ;)

Comment: @Didier, you're looking for `mod_sspi`

Comment: @Nathan: `mod_sspi` requires the Apache SVN server to run on Windows. (I'd like to be wrong on that ...)

Answer (score 10):

I have personnally successfully used repositories created in Linux on the Windows platform and vice-versa.

There are no incompatibilities from a platform point of view.

You still should be careful about the Subversion software version used on each platform, since the Subversion repository format has evolved over time.

The best course of action to avoid any pitfall is to do a complete dump of your repository:

```
$ svnadmin dump /var/svn/repos > full.dump
```

and load it on the target server:

```
C:\svn> svnadmin load newrepos < full.dump
```

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate FSFS repos without doing anything (even BDB just needs a small tweak as long as CPU arch didn't change), but as mentioned, the "safe way" is to dump and load.

I've done linux->windows migration before and you should be well aware that your performance will suffer badly if using (the default) FSFS.  NTFS is just a horrible file system when it comes to many files / small files.  I have observed things like 'svn ls' to see an order of magnitude drop in performance.  Better test first to see if you're still happy.

Comment: Nathan makes a good point about NTFS.  If you do intend to run your Subversion repositories on Windows, make sure you do a dump and load of the repo and by all means make sure sharding is turned on when you load.  Sharding is available in the 1.5.x and 1.6.x versions of Subversion.

Comment: @jgifford25: sharding can help performance (not talking of Explorer viewability) when you have hundreds of thousands of revisions, but even with fewer revisions NTFS is just plain slow for any file operation (ACLS, etc). (I did test Malcom Rowe's sharding script on Windows when he first implemented sharding).

Answer (score 1):

in order to load it on the windows machine...you need to 
1.open VisualSVN Server 
2.create the new repositories with the (reponame) you want 
3.open cmd
4.navigate to c:\program files\VisualSVN Server\bin>
5.type

```
svnadmin.exe load "c:\[path where you have assigned for your repositories]\(reponame)" < "c:\[path where the dump file is]\(reponame).dump
```

eg. if i have (myrepo.dump) copied on my "c:\dump_files" from the linux machine and I have assigned "c:\new_svn" for repositories location then the command should be in cmd

```
c:\program files\VisualSVN Server\bin>svnadmin load "c:\new_svn\myrepo_new" < "c:\dump_files\myrepo.dump"
```

but first make sure that the myrepo_new has been created in visualSVN server manager

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you should be able to copy each repository with its underlying file structure from the Linux server to the Windows server and use it without issue as long as both servers use the same major version of Subversion (i.e. 1.6.x, or 1.5.x).

However, the best advice is to follow SirDarius' answer and dump each repo on the Linux server and reload them on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to make sure that your firewall is off or you firewall is allowing the traffic for svn. If u are still not able to access svn server developed in linux on windows then you make sure that you are not there in `c://` you have to be in different drive to do checkout